# Why different microcontrollers design with different peripherals rather than using same peripherals set?

Tags: microcontroller

Why different micro-controllers design with different peripherals rather than using same peripherals set?

I think reason behind this is power , size , cost and different micro-controllers have different uses. Am I correct or is there any other reasons behind it?

Comment: you mean like cars are designed with more doors or less, more room or less, more power or less, rear window wipers or not, more cup holders, etc?

Comment: because there is a market for those options, if folks will buy enough of them then you make them.  more pins, more timers less timers more flash less flash more ram less ram, more cup holders or less.  nothing complicated nor magic about it.

Comment: the peripherals take valuable chip real estate and when you are making products that are one to a few dollars each and the products they go into its a game of pennies, they need to cost reduce their products down to fractions of a dollar. So you would not be profitable, or even stay in business if you made only one $5 - $10 part with a wide array of peripherals when your competitors have $2 and $3 parts or less but in many varieties. Your parts would never even be considered, not even worth investigating at those prices. Each peripheral has a cost, the more you have the more the part costs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct. Citing the comments below your post, there are many cars for different purposes, and the same goes on for microcontrollers. The only difference from car market is that, probably, you can not have a car equally good for off-road *and* Formula 1, while with MUCs this more possible.

As a MCU grows with its capabilities, price and complexity also grow, and nobody wants to use a costly and complicated MCU to do a very simple job.

There are MCUs specialized in networking, or in signal processing, display (LCD?) capabilities, or other things. Most of the MCUs have anyway some common background, i.e. peripherals which are always useful like timers and digital I/O.

Then there is the CPU/core part. Programmers or engineers are content to use and reuse the same CPU core, and often you find a lot of CPU with the same core architecture, but different peripheral sets. But again, you don't need a powerful core for doing simple hardware tasks; and instead you need power, speed and memory to drive certain peripherals.